# Using Batik with Yii - Fails in the app but works in terminal

Tags: php, shell, svg, png, batik

I'm trying to add SVG to .png conversion into my Yii app, using the Batik rasterizing library. Currently I'm working locally on a Mac running OSX 10.6.7, PHP 5.3.4 and Java 1.6.0_24.

When I run the PHP script that deals with the conversion, using...

```
$output = shell_exec(java -jar batik/batik-rasterizer.jar -m image/png -d pdf_temp/file.png -w 800 pdf_temp/file.svg)
```

Batik fails with the (unhelpful) error:

```
About to transcode 1 SVG file(s)
Converting file.svg to pdf_temp/file.png ...  file_1310581599.png

Error while converting SVG
```

However, using...

```
java -jar batik/batik-rasterizer.jar -m image/png -d pdf_temp/file.png -w 800 pdf_temp/file.svg
```

...in Terminal works a treat and saves the .png file in the /pdf_temp/ directory along with its original .svg

So what's different about the PHP/apache environment that's causing Batik to fail when Terminal is fine?

EDIT:

After chatting with some colleagues we think it could be the fact that Java needs to run as root - which it does from Terminal but not within the web server.

Adding...

```
2>&1 1> /dev/null
```

To my Batik shell_exec() command reveals the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError: Can't connect to window server - not enough permissions.
```

Any ideas as to how I can run Java as root with the web server environment? Or allow it to perform the functions I require?

---

Comment: You should use the same shell/environment if you want to produce the same result.

Comment: Can you check the permissions and owners on the pdf_temp folder and the files in it? The web server is likely running as a different user to you.

Comment: @waitinforatrain - already thought of that I'm afraid, I've checked the user and 777'd the folder long ago...

Answer (score 0):

> -Djava.awt.headless=true

http://www.emcken.dk/weblog/archives/25-svg-rasterizer-with-batik.html

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working with Batik and Yii as well. Check the output and the source files' path. I provided the whole path and it is working now. It seems that Yii doesn't stand where your view is, instead Yii current location is your webroot. In my case I fixed like this:

```
    define ('BATIK_PATH', '/var/www/wattquotes/protected/views/calculator/reports/batik/batik-rasterizer.jar');
    $typeString = ' -m image/jpeg';
    $outfile = ' /var/www/wattquotes/protected/views/calculator/reports/batik/temp/pic.jpg';
    $width = ' -w 600';
    $tempName = ' /var/www/wattquotes/protected/views/calculator/reports/batik/temp/proposal.svg';
    $output = shell_exec("java -jar ". BATIK_PATH ." $typeString -d $outfile $width $tempName");
```

It works!